# Need a mobile friendly website working exactly the same functionally as the one which is online

Tags: html, asp.net

I work for telecom company in India. My work involves checking the connectivity of the network through IPs and the ping through it. Our company has a website http://117.239.43.170/ping_select.aspx for it. The problem is the website isn't mobile friendly and I need to zoom in and out every time I go to that site. I am familiar with the basics of front end. I have created the mobile friendly version of that website and stored it in my mobile, but it is redirecting me to the same website. So my question is, is there any way I can use a mobile friendly version of that website and still get the same results

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you making an android application and control (send and receive) the website in the background. This website uses a HTML form and very few inputs so it wont be that hard to go with the java staff.

Alternatively you can make a browser plugin for your phone browser to control the website in background and at the front end you get your desired UI.

I guess you dont have the access to upload your website to that server so you cannot request to your BSNL server from a local website (or whatever else). The BSNL server wont allow cross server requests. The best bet you can make is layering below that website over any other programs.

Comment: That was very helpful ! So, to make a browser plugin, will my basic knowledge of HTML and CSS be enough ? Please provide me with leads to get started..

Comment: I am suggesting you two links. 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted
and..

http://www.sitepoint.com/create-chrome-extension-10-minutes-flat/

And yeah. a good hands on HTML, CSS and Javascript will be enough for you. Good luck!

Comment: If I get time tonight i will make a demo project and try to connect it with the website you provided. Will let you know tomorrow

Comment: Ohh..please..that would be really helpful